# Do not show deprecated tags in tag autocomplete

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I was reviewing [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701238/git-how-delete-file-from-remote-repository) [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8637955).
Here is a screenshot of it:

[image: Review of suggested edit]

I thought that the suggested tags were not necessary, so I rejected it. Now my point is about the tag [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete): As written in its description, it is deprecated (and I agree with that). I assume that it cannot be deleted yet, because there are ~7k questions. But would not it be better to also NOT show it in the tag autocomplete?

At the moment of writing this, the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147891/google-script-entire-form-delete) tagged with [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete) was asked about 9 hours ago. So, users are still adding that tag to their questions. I think deprecated tags should not be shown in the tag autocomplete. This will at least help to not increase the number of questions with deprecated tags.

Comment: Related: [a burnination request for \[delete\] and the related \[deletion\] and \[deleting\].](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298476/3488231)

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that there is nothing but the description saying that the tag is deprecated.  There is nothing in stackoverflow that actually marks a tag as being deprecated.  First they would have to come up with a way to mark tags as being deprecated and then decide who/how tags can be marked as being deprecated.

If they were to do this I would think they could allow 5k rep users to decide as they are allowed to approve tag wiki edits.  I think they could even integrate this into the tag wiki edit UI where if you have 5k rep you get a check box to suggest that the tag be marked as deprecated.  Then in the suggested edit queue if a tag has been suggested as being deprecated then next to where it says it is a tag wiki edit it should also call out that it has been suggested to be deprecated. If it then goes through the review and is accepted then the tag would be marked as deprecated.

Comment: Exactly SO needs a deprecated or deleted field within its DB to hide tags that have been deemed as not usable by the community

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Thats why I suggest that it goes through the review queue.  if the reviewers don't think it should be depreciated then they should reject it.  As is just changing the wiki to say it is depreciated goes through this same process.